# comparing an element with all elements in a list

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala now, and I have a scenario where I have to compare an element (say `num`) with all the elements in a list.

Assume,

```
val MyList = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If `num` is equal to anyone the elements in the list, I need to return `true`. I know to do it recursively using the `head` and `tail` functions, but is there a simpler way to it (I think I'll be able to do it using `foreach`, but I'm not sure how to implement it exactly)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is number of possibilities:

```
val x = 3
MyList.contains(x)
!MyList.forall(y => y != x) // early exit, basically the same as .contains
```

If you plan to do it frequently, you may consider to convert your list to Set, cause every `.contains` lookup on list in worst case is proportional to number of elements, whereas on Set it is [effectively constant](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html)

```
val mySet = MyList.toSet
mySet.contains(x)
```

or simply:

```
mySet(x)
```

Comment: The runtime complexity of contains for sets depends on the implementation. The best worst case performance is O(log n)

Answer (score 3):

A `contains` method is pretty standard for lists in any language. Scala's `List` has it too:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 3):

As others have answered, the `contains` method on the list will do exactly this, and it's the most understandable/performant way.

Looking at your closing comments though, you *wouldn't* be able to do it (in an elegant fashion) with `foreach`, since that returns `Unit`.  Foreach "does" something for each element, but you don't get any result back.  It's useful for logging/println statements, but it doesn't act as a transformation.

If you want to run a function on every element individually, you would use `map`, which returns a List of the results of applying the function.  So  assuming num = 3, then `MyList.map(_ == num)` would return `List(false, false, true, false)`.  Since you're looking for a single result, and not a list of results, then this is not what you're after.

In order to collapse a sequence of things into a single result, you would use a *fold* over the data.  Folding involves a function that takes two arguments (the result so far, and the current thing in the list) and returns the new running result.  So that this can work on the very first element, you also need to provide the initial value to use for the ongoing result (usually some sort of zero).

In your particular case, then, you want a `Boolean` answer at the end - "was an element found that was equal to `num`".  So the running result would be "have I seen an element so far that was equal to `num`".  Which means the initial value is `false`.  And the function itself should return `true` if an element has already been seen, or if the current element is equal to `num`.

Putting this together, it would look like this:

```
MyList.foldLeft(false) { case (runningResult, listElem) =>
   // return true if runningResult is true, or if listElem is the target number
   runningResult || listElem == num
}
```

This doesn't have the nice aspect of stopping as soon as the target value has been found - and it's nowhere near as concise as calling `MyList.contains`.  But as an instructional example, this is how you could implement this yourself from the primitive functional operations on a list.

Answer (score 2):

`List` has a method for that:

```
val found = MyList.contains(num)
```